# AJAX different data records in Response Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am working on a site using HTML/CSS/JS and AJAX for connecting to the server. (new to web development)

I currently have this to get data and put it in an array.

```
var addresses = [];

$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: 'GetAddresses.php',
     data: {"type":"check"},
     success: function(response){
         alert(response);
         addresses.push(response) // add values from php to array
     }
    });
```

But what if php echoed an address, a name, and a city for example. How could I access those different values?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What's the response?

Comment: Update your HTML DOM directly from javascript.

Comment: Ideally `response` would be a JavaScript object (the server should return JSON) and you can access whatever properties/values on it that you like.  Can you provide details about the specific problem you're observing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you would write PHP that outputs structured data, e.g. JSON, and then parse that on the client.

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: application/json");

    $data = [ "address" => "foo", "name" => "bar", "city" => "baz" ];

    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

and then on the client:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: 'GetAddresses.php',
     data: {"type":"check"},
     success: function(response){
         alert(response);
         console.log(response.address);
         console.log(response.name);
         console.log(response.city);
     }
 });
```

---

Unrelated to the focus of your question, [pushing data into an array in the wider scope from an Ajax callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron) is likely to cause you problems.

Comment: Your link has a lot to say about scope in JavaScript, but I don't see the part that relates to your specific warning. Could you quote the relevant text?

Comment: It's the whole accepted answer. Worry about it when you find the array unexpectedly empty.